# How do I update a given SQL row in C# when it has no known or guaranteed unique ID?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I need to go through a database finding all text-like fields, checking for a particular set of URLs that might be in these fields and modify it using some regex.

The actual text manipulation part is fine, but since I'm generically going through tables, some of which seem to not have primary keys, I'm wondering how to update these rows once I've read this. I'll give a dummy example below.

```
foreach(var matchingTable in tables){
    foreach(var matchingColumn in columns){
        SqlCommand currentCommand = new SqlCommand("select * from @matchingTable;");
        currentCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@matchingTable", matchingTable);
            using (SqlDataReader reader = currentCommand.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    if(/* logic to check reader[matchingColumn]*/){
                        /*edit row to change column matchingColumn, a row which I can't be sure has any uniquely identifying factor*/
                    }
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Is it possible to edit this arbitrary row or will I have to change how I'm doing this?

Comment: dont use addWithValue but just add https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a table do not have guaranteed unique id then there is no value of a duplicated record. And so if a duplicated record is also updated then no harm will be done.

You can consider all the fields as one composite field and perform the update. 
One thing to keep in mind is the duplicate records will also be updated.

Comment: I do generally get that idea but I was hoping there would be some way the code could handle it during runtime. For example, as a human in SQL Server Management Studio, I can click Edit Rows, look for an erroneous value in one of the rows, and edit it. I didn't need to know the exact row ID or unique identifier, I just knew I was on that row and wanted to edit it. But yes your composite key idea seems sensible, might go down that route :)

Answer (score 0):

This might be easier to solve inside the database.  You can write a cursor equivalent to the two for-loops to select the table and column.  From there you can write a simple UPDATE/WHERE using your regular expression.